# iOS Storyboard Localization: Manually editing generated files

Tags: ios, localization, xcode-storyboard

I'm in the process of localizing an iOS application. I've run into a few issues though - the main one being storyboard localization. I need to add textual context to each string so that the translator can understand how the string is used. For example, in my storyboard localization for English, I will change:

```
/* Class = "UILabel"; text = "Label"; ObjectID = "1Sf-fE-WR8"; */
"1Sf-fE-WR8.text" = "Label";
```

to:

```
/* Context: this label is the header of the settings screen */
"1Sf-fE-WR8.text" = "Label";
```

Firstly - is this a bad idea? The problem is that if I ever have to re-generate the localization for the storyboard, all edits I've done on the file will disappear. How then, in the future, if I add a new element to the storyboard, will I get that element into the .strings file without regenerating it?

Note:

a) I have tried "Export For Localization", but this always results in an error "Localization failed to read a strings file"

b) The project is set up in a strange way: there is a parent project which has existing localizations, and we've added a sub-target which has it's own localized files, but the overall localization export mechanism applies to the project as a whole, and I'm worried that fiddling with it will corrupt the existing work.

Any help or thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There's a "Comment for the localizer" text field that you can use to provide the label's usage context.

[image: Comment For Localizer Text Field]

Not sure if it's still relevant to you or if it was present back in the days of Xcode 7.

Comment: Thank you. I've since moved on from that project (without better solution), but I will give this a try as soon as I get a chance.